# ScrollMagic and Scroll Snap Aign bugged

Tags: html, scrollmagic, scroll-snap-type

After creating a page split into two parts like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvbL-VqACyM, I added scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; for the page to automatically scroll to a given section.

The problem is that when it scrolls to the second section, then back to the first, a white box appears above the element that is the trigger element for a while.

I put a movie on my google drive. You can see the error in the top right corner. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19fkSqCsJF1mHE1ju4fS4mqtJ_tABj6B3?usp=sharing

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="two_parts">
            <div id="left_side">
                <section class="scroll">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem magnam eaque recusandae error officia? Porro dolorem quas provident. Aliquid optio ut natus illo, rem dignissimos explicabo quas deserunt dolor vitae?
                </section>
                <section class="scroll">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, soluta. Dolor nihil animi quaerat qui totam? Provident, quidem deserunt dolore ab, quos, voluptatibus cum fugiat officia unde atque repellat deleniti.
                </section>
            </div>
            <div id="right_side" class="right_side">
                <section>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut quidem minima deleniti quisquam vel autem quaerat animi laboriosam nemo amet? Officia repellendus iure architecto at sed minima, sint quidem illo?
                </section>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div  style="width: 100vw-10px; height: 100vh; background-color: aqua; position: relative;"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function splitScroll(){
            const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

            new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                duration: '100%',
                triggerElement: '.right_side',
                triggerHook: 0,
                container: '#right_side',
            })
            .setPin('.right_side')
            .addIndicators()
            .addTo(controller);
            
        }
        splitScroll();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.scroll {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}

#two_parts {
    height: 200vh;
    display: flex;
}

#left_side {
    width: 70%;
}

#left_side section {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f2f0fb;
}

#right_side {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#3728a5, #7b4cbb);
}

#right_side section {
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 30px 60px -12px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 18px 36px -18px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#3728a5, #7b4cbb);
}
```